# setting bool value from a different class before navigating to that class

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm trying to set a value to true after the user has been authenticated, so that they can use the page after authentication. When I set the value to true and redirect them to that same page that value is false again. I'm sure it has to do with different instances of the class but I dont know how to fix it.

This is the class that sets the value:

```
if (IsUserAuthorized())
    {
        Admin admin = new Admin
                          {
                              IsAuthorized = true
                          };
        Response.Redirect("~/Admin.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        LblErrorMessage.Text = "Please check your \"User Name\" or \"Password\" and try again.";
    }
```

This is the class that needs to know the value:

```
public partial class Admin : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public bool IsAuthorized { get; set; }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsAuthorized)
            {//Do something}            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/UserAuthentication.aspx");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

classes do not persist between pages. What you need is either of the following two

1. Store the login status in cookies. That is how most sites do it. That is how e.g. on an email client you can navigate to various pages but still stay logged in.
2. Store the login status as session variables. Your login variable (true/false) resides in session.

Comment: great I've changed my code to this:bool IsAuthorized;
            if(Session["IsAuthorized"] != null)
            {
                IsAuthorized = (bool)Session["IsAuthorized"];
            }
            else
            {
                IsAuthorized = false;
            }